# Evaluating the limits of summation.

Tags: calculus, limits

How is this limit  evaluated? $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt r}$$

I tried expanding the summation but I got nowhere.All the denominators become $\infty$ and I get the answer as zero. But the actual answer is 4. Where have I went wrong? What method should be applied to solve this question?

Comment: Do a comparison series/integral. In a (very) precise sense, $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \simeq \int_1^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx \simeq 2\sqrt{n}$ when $n\to\infty$. Then, you have a better grip on $f((n+2)^2)-f(n^2-1)$.

Comment: You want to find some useful bounds $f(n)<\sum<g(n)$ and then see what happens to $f$ and $g$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Also, every single term will tend to $0$, but you have $(n+2)^2-n^2+1= 4n+2\to\infty$ of them. So you get an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$, explaining "where you have gone wrong." (and for what it's worth, @GerryMyerson's suggestion is much simpler and more effective here than mine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all $r\in\Bigl[\frac1{n^2},\frac1{(n+2)^2}\Bigr]$, you have 
$$\frac1{n+2}\le \frac1{\sqrt r}\le\frac1{n},\enspace\text{so}\quad\frac{(n+2)^2-n^2+1}{n+2}=\frac{4n+5}{n+2}\le \sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt r}\le \frac{4n+5}{n}$$
The squeezing principle shows the limit is $4$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+2}\leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\leq  \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Lozebges: Really was out of my mind… Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 4):

We have that (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals))
$$
\int_{n^2}^{(n+2)^2+1}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx\le\sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt r}\le\int_{n^2-1}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx.
$$
Since
$$
\int_{n^2}^{(n+2)^2+1}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx=2\Bigl[\sqrt{(n+2)^2+1}-n\Bigr]\ge 4
$$
and
$$
\int_{n^2-1}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx=2\Bigl[n+2-\sqrt{n^2-1}\Bigr]=2\cdot\frac{(n+2)^2-n^2+1}{n+2+\sqrt{n^2-1}}\to4
$$
as $n\to\infty$, we conlcude that the limit is $4$.

Comment: Is not this the correct order?$$
\int_{n^2-1}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx\le\sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2}\frac1{\sqrt r}\le\int_{n^2}^{(n+2)^2+1}\frac1{\sqrt x}dx.
$$

Comment: @AnanthKamath Thanks for your comment, but I think it is the other way round since $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is a decreasing function.

Comment: you are correct ! I forgot for a moment that $x^\frac {-1}{2}$ is decreasing  . Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: This is really a great solution.